# unmet dependencies, not installable, and no installation candidate

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I faced this problem installing different apps now and then, but this time, it is kitscenarist. while installing, both with deb file or from repositories, I get the error:

```
kitscenarist : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Obviously trying to install that package I get this:

```
Package qtbase-abi-5-15-2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

That app is one of the main tools I use for my job, anyway to fix that error?

Ubuntu 22.04 (yes, beta)
GNOME 42.0
and
[KitScenarist](https://kitscenarist.ru/en/download.html) is an app to write stories and scenarios which I use this code to install:

```
echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/AndnoVember:/KITScenarist/xUbuntu_21.10/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:AndnoVember:KITScenarist.list
curl -fsSL https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:AndnoVember:KITScenarist/xUbuntu_21.10/Release.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home_AndnoVember_KITScenarist.gpg > /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kitscenarist
```

Comment: Hello, 22.04 Does not exist yet. Till it does any question re this unreleased OS are off topic on this site.

Comment: @David but 22.04 Beta DOES exist, doesn` it?
AND
is the problem limited to 22.04 (beta)? I have faced the same problem in 21.10 etc.

Comment: Beta products have never been supported on this site.

Comment: There is no package named `kitscenarist` in the Ubuntu repositories. So it's unclear where you are getting this package from, or what process you are following to get the error. Links in your Question above to a source or to install instructions would help a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just did

Comment: @guiverc Now that I updated to latest packages and I actually got 22.04 (which IS a release now), AND I still have the same problem may I ask the same question again?